# How do I automatically set the value of a variable when a class object is created?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
}
```

which is a part of a Custom Control. And when the developer creates a `Test` object, I need my class to automatically calculate the `Size` of the text of the `Title` property.

I'm having a major brain fail right now, and I have no idea what to even search for. I'm just lost for words.

---

How do I automagically measure the size of the Title text when the developer creates the test object:

```
Test test = new Test()
{
    Title = "This is some text.",
};
```

I have some ideas, but they don't work, and I feel that they're kinda crazy, so I'm not sure if I should post them.

Comment: Don't use auto-generated properties and add additional code in the set accessor. It depends on what you mean by "measure" the string, whether thats just the length or you really want the size in pixels displayed on the screen. You can do one, you don't have enough info for the other.

Comment: What do you mean by _size_? You can measure the length of a string (which is the type for your Title property) but not size.

Comment: @RonBeyer Oh sorry, I should have clarified. I am going to measure the string like this: `size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Title, this.Font);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in the setter of the `Title` property. When you use that syntax to create an instance of `Test` you're actually running through the property setter after the object is instantiated.

```
public class Test
{
    public Size Size { get; set; }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            Size = // calculate size of _title
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be the right (more right at least) way to do it, although the OP should use a separate function to measure the size since it needs to be recalculated not only when the title changes, but when the font changes.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do. I don't know how my brain can fail me so massively. I've done this in the past so many times. It's really embarrassing to ask these questions, but I have to sometimes because I just can't seem to fix my brain. Thanks! (I'm just waiting for the timer to run out so I can accept the answer)

Answer (score 3):

Like this. It'll automatically calculate your size for you whenever you call Size.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public readonly Size Size 
    { 
        get
        {
            return TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Title, this.Font);
        } 
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Test test = new Test()
{
    Title = "This is some text.",
};
var result = test.Size; //Should give you your calculated size when called.
```

Comment: Your getter for `Size` doesn't return anything.  Why not just return the result and get rid of the private `_size` field.

Comment: @juharr Ah you're right, that was some leftover code when I was making my response.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the constructor:

```
public class Test
{
    private string _title = null;
    private Size _size = null;

    public Test(String title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get { return _title; }; set { _title = value; _size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Title, this.Font); } }

    public readonly Size Size { get; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted too early.  Corrected.

Comment: Might want to edit one more time, your constructor is private, you wouldn't be able to create an instance of the class.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP  wants... he wants to measure the size based on the title text

Comment: @RonBeyer: Our edits must have crossed.  Already done, thank you though!

Comment: and you should combine with @craigw 's . answer (props to Craig) with the setter always setting Size correctly

Comment: Added your calculation logic and added readonly to Size property.  Props to @JoshL.  I think this now combines the best features of the various answers.  It shows  constructing the object with a title, and use of getter only Size to prevent getting out of synch and setting of Size in the Title setter to always be up to date, with your calculation of Size.

Comment: A property cannot be half auto and half not.  You have to give the getter of the `Title` property a body and return `_title`.

Answer (score 0):

**Option A.**  Make `Size` a derived function.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Size 
    { 
        get
        {
           return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title)) ? 0 : Title.Length;
        } 
    }
}
```

In this way, size is always in sync with `Title`.

**Option B.** Intercept `Title.set`
When ever you change the Title, Size is updated.

```
public class Test
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get { return _title; } 
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            Size = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? 0 : Title.Length;
        } 
    }
    public int Size { get; set; }   
}
```

PD. For measuring strings, `int` should be enough no need for `Size` (designed for 2D measures).